# Ria Framework DomainDataSource MoveToNextPage, MoveToPage, MoveToFirstPage doesn't move pages

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ria

I'm attempting to write a save results extension to the DomainDatasourceView.
I can successfully write the contents of the current page of results but when I attempt to call MoveToNextPage(), the PageIndex stays current. MSDN docs regarding this don't provide any details other than MoveToNextPage returns a bool is it successfully moves to the next page.

The following sample code results in an infinite loop, and the Current page is never changed.

```
private void WriteResults(DomainDataSourceView resultsview)
{
    StringBuilder csvdata = new StringBuilder();
    ... Do Work on current page ...
    if(resultsview.CanChangePage && resultsview.MoveToNextPage())
    {
        csvdata.Append(WriteResults(resultsview));
    }
}
```

Do I need to listen for the PageChanged Event to continue Saving Results?

Do I need to call Load on the DomainDataSource for each page?

The [MSDN Docs on DomainDataSourceView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ria.domaindatasourceview_members%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) doesn't go into too much details on this subject.

[Edit]
After playing around some more, I was able to determine that the Move...Page commands do call the the DomainDataSource Load operation, however its another Async call, so any consecutive work that needs to be done on the loaded pages, should be handled accordingly.

Comment: If its an async call then where is the Completed event on the page move? As far as I can tell these methods don't work at all and the msdn docs on pagedcollection are complete bs